# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource (POST request with object)

Tags: ajax, axios, asp.net-web-api2, httprequest, asp.net-ajax

I enabled CORS in my web api application

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

All the requests are working fine. but `when i pass an object to the post method` i get this:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:44367/api/Users/Create. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

```
// WORKING
return axios.post(url)
return axios.get(url)


// NOT WORKING

let model = {
    firstName: 'a',
}

return axios.post(url, model);

// or with configuration

let axiosConfig = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true,
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
            }
        };

return axios.post(url, model, axiosConfig);
```

Also posting with postman is working, with the following body

```
//{
//  "model" : {
//      "name":"firstName"
//  }
//}
```

i have set a break-point in `Application_BeginRequest` event and it wont hit.

Controller Action

```
public ClientResponseModel<User> Create([FromBody]UserAddModel model)
{
   ///.....
}
```

Request Header

```
Host: localhost:44367
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-credentials,access-control-allow-origin,content-type
Referer: http://localhost:44346/Registration.aspx
Origin: http://localhost:44346
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response Header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Public: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcYWxpLmtcc291cmNlXEF6dXJlXExlYmFuZXNlTGF3c1xDTVNcYXBpXFVzZXJzXENyZWF0ZQ==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 24 Feb 2020 13:56:15 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the following in my `web.config` to make it work without any custom configuration on axios:

```xml
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
   CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
   corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
  corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200")); 
  corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control,     Allow-Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization", "Origin, Accept", "X-Requested-With", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Header" )); // this allows all headers
   corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization", "Access-Control-Request-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
   corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**",corsConfiguration);
    return new CorsFilter();
}
```

I used this and it work fine for me

Comment: this is for spring boot

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I allowed cors from both application side and server side. But after searching, i found out there might be region issue so i added proxy url with the original url and it worked for me. Here is a code:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token);

var requestOptions = {
    
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    Vary: 'Origin',
};
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const url = "your url";

fetch(proxyurl + url, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: Keep in mind that ```https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/``` should be used for development purposes only